# Hibernate Query on self join table fails

Tags: sql, hibernate, orm

I have table that can represent a tree.

```
key       number(10) NOT NULL,
parentkey number(10) NOT NULL,
name      varchar(20),
```

And a class representing it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "example")
public class Example
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "KEY")
    private long key;

    @Column(name = "NAME")  
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parentkey",referencedColumnName="key")
    private Example parent;

    public Example()
    {
        parent = this;
    }
```

When I try to query on an instance and its parent I get

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: parent.name of: com.Example

Here is how I build the Criteria query:

```
        Example dsd = ...;
         ...
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Example.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("name", dsd.getName()));       

        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("parent.name", dsd.getParent().getName()));

        return crit.list();
```

I could do this in raw sql, but I would rather not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an [alias](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html):

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Example.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("name", dsd.getName()));       
crit.createAlias("parent", "parent");
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("parent.name", dsd.getParent().getName()));
```