# How make a query with Hibernate and applying Restrincions on a field that is an Object

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, restrictions

This is the entity **Utente**; as you can see, there is a field **autenticazione** that is another entity, called **Autenticazione**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "utente")
@Component
public class Utente implements Serializable{
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "utente", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Valid
    private Autenticazione autenticazione;  
    ...
}
```

this is the entity **Autenticazione**

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "autenticazione")
public class Autenticazione implements Serializable{
    ...
    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Utente.class)    
    @JoinColumn(name="utente", referencedColumnName="id") 
    private Utente utente;      

    @Column(name = "username")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z0-9.-_]*$")
    private String username;
    ...
}
```

I have to make a query that allow me to get the object **Utente** from the database, searching by the value of the the field **username** of the object **Autenticazione**, that is a field of the entity **Utente**.

I should do something like this:

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSessionFactory().createCriteria(Utente.class);
criteria.add(
             Restrictions.eq("autenticazione.username",            
             utenteForSearch.getAutenticazione().getUsername())
             );
```

Is it possibile to use Hibernate and use as "where" a field of an Entity that is an Entity itself?

Thank you

Comment: Create an [alias](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31481441/4754790).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenter (@Dragan Bozanovic) is correct, you want this:

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSessionFactory().createCriteria(Utente.class);
crit.createAlias("autenticazione", "autenticazione");
criteria.add(
             Restrictions.eq("autenticazione.username",            
             utenteForSearch.getAutenticazione().getUsername())
             );
```